# PHP compressing image into thumbnail reduces thumbnail quality alot

Tags: php, thumbnails, gd

I'm creating thumbnails in PHP, but when I display the thumbnail on screen, the quality drastically drops. I'll post the php resample code:

```php
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

imagejpeg($image_p, null, 99);                                                  
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $filewidth, $fileheight);                     
$imageformat($image_p, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."$filepath_thumb"); // Thumbnail Folder
```

How do I fix it. I've had people suggest tweaking the imagejpeg(); line. Any suggestions?

Comment: `imagecopyresampled()` is still a blunt instrument. Use [`imagescale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php) instead with anything other than 'nearest neighbour', which is roughly what resampling is doing.